# How can I accept NULL and ignore init in shiny observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

It seems that shiny is broken because it doesn't do what you expect it to do. I have this simple code:

```
obseveEvent(input$foo, {

}, ignoreNULL = FALSE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
```

and according to the documentation if there is `NULL` you will get the event on init even if you have `ignoreInit = TRUE` (which seems contradictory).

I use my custom input and I've tried to return FALSE when shiny first try to get the value, but still, the event is fired, with FALSE, I even tried to return `1` and it doesn't work. It seems that `ignoreInit` doesn't work at all if there is `ignoreNULL = FALSE`.

How can I really accept NULL and ignore init in shiny observeEvent?

Basically I want to get NULL when user unselect everything after he select something, but on init I don't want the event the fire.

Comment: I tried replicating it with a small app but in my environment  it works as specified. I have no trouble to ignore the event on init and run it later when it is `NULL`. Could you show us what is behind `input$foo`?

Comment: @Jan I need to investigate since I have more code and my custom framework on top of Shiny.

Comment: similarly afflicted as you @jcubi - wonder if you sorted this....???

Comment: @malcook I didn't solve it, I don't remember what I did. Unfortunately, I no longer work on the Shiny project.